# Train existing object detection nanodet model - (Android App/Python Server)

Tags: python, java, android, object-detection, ncnn

I am using nanodet as object detection library in my Android (java) application, here is the example of Android app: https://github.com/RangiLyu/nanodet/tree/main/demo_android_ncnn

My goal is to train and build new data model on top of existing one: by taking single image, and providing label name; I want to send these data to Python server, which is expected to respond .bin and .param file (NCNN type)

I want to add new labels (class_names) included into my existing Android app dynamically by taking new .bin and .param file into consideration.

My question is: how should I add these new labels (class_names) into my Android app dynamically without rebuilding the application or modifying the code?

I also tried this Android nanodet project: https://github.com/nihui/ncnn-android-nanodet but was unable to figure out how can I achieve the end result.